# Run R script after input in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Good morning everyone,

I have a Shiny application that collects 5 inputs from the users and stores them into variables.

Then, I would be able to use another R script that would run based on the information provided by the user.

Here is a sample of my Shiny App :

```
jscode <- "shinyjs.closeWindow = function() { window.close(); }"

#Define UI for application

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  #App title
  headerPanel("Filters applied for Powerpoints"),

   #Panel to display the filters
  sidebarPanel(
    #Select dates
    dateInput(inputId = "startDate", label = "Start date : ", value = "2018-12-01", format = "yyyy/mm/dd"),
    dateInput(inputId = "endDate", label = "End date : ", value = "2018-12-31", format = "yyyy/mm/dd"),

    #Select brand template
    selectInput("Brand", label = "Select brand : ", choices = list("Carat" = "Carat", "Amplifi" = "Amplifi", "iProspect" = "iProspect", "Isobar" = "Isobar")),

    #Select medium type
    selectInput("Medium", label = "Select medium type : ", choices = list("Social Post" = "Social Post", "Display" = "Display", "Programmatic" = "Programmatic", "SEA" = "SEA")),

    #Enter the plan ID of your campaign
    textInput("Camp", label = "Enter the plan ID of your campaign : ", value = ""),

    #Button to close the window, then run script
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c("closeWindow")),
    actionButton("close", "Close and run")
  ),
  mainPanel()
)

#Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session){
  observe({
    startDate <<- input$startDate
    endDate <<- input$endDate
    brand <<- input$Brand
    medium <<- input$Medium
    campaign <<- input$Camp
  })
  observeEvent(input$close, {
    js$closeWindow()
    stopApp()
  })
  source("C:/Users/RPeete01/Desktop/Automated powerpoints/Datorama R/Datorama reporting R/DatoramaSocial.R")
}


#Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've used the source function but it doesn't work.

If someone has an idea, please let me know.

Thanks a lot,

Rémi

Comment: Can you make your source at the top instead of server and try?

Comment: Write `source("C:/Users/RPeete01/Desktop/Automated powerpoints/Datorama R/Datorama reporting R/DatoramaSocial.R")` at the end of your script, after `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take advantage of built in `onStop` functions in shiny to execute some functions before the `stopApp()` call

```
library(shiny)
if (interactive()) {
  # Open this application in multiple browsers, then close the browsers.
  shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage("onStop demo",actionButton("close", "Close and run")),

    server = function(input, output, session) {
      onStop(function() cat("Session stopped\n"))

      observeEvent(input$close, {
        stopApp()
      })
    },

    onStart = function() {
      cat("Doing application setup\n")

      onStop(function() {
        cat("Doing application cleanup, your functions go here\n")
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a function to replace your script, you can source your script by supplying an environment to the `local` option. This environment must contain the objects needed by your script. Something like that:

```
mylist <- reactiveVal() # we will store the inputs in a reactive list

observe({ # create the list
  mylist(list(
    startDate = input$startDate,
    endDate = input$endDate,
    brand = input$Brand,
    medium = input$Medium,
    campaign = input$Camp))
})

observeEvent(input$runScript, { # "runScript" is an action button
  source("myscript.R", local = list2env(mylist()))
})
```

---

## EDIT

Here is a full example.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("text", "Enter text", value = "test"),
  actionButton("runScript", "Run")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  mylist <- reactiveVal() # we will store the inputs in a reactive list

  observe({ # create the list
    mylist(list(
      text = input$text))
  })

  observeEvent(input$runScript, { # "runScript" is an action button
    source("myscript.R", local = list2env(mylist()))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**File myscript.R:**

```
writeLines(text, "output.txt")
```

When I run the app and click on the button, the file `output.txt` is correctly created (i.e. the script is correctly sourced).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I tried your solution, but when clicking on the actionbutton, nothing happens. Still need to look into that.

Comment: @RémiPts Weird. And with `eventReactive` instead of `observeEvent` ?

Comment: Same, nothing new :(

Comment: @RémiPts I've added an example in my answer. For me it perfectly works. What your script is supposed to do ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I've the same problem, highly appreciate your help. thanks in advance  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129562/in-r-shiny-how-to-fix-error-in-sourcing-app-as-nothing-changes-when-clicking-on

Answer (score 0):

Your script `DatoramaSocial.R` should be formulated as a function that takes your 5 input values as arguments. As to the return value, well you haven't told us what you want to do with it. By formulating it as a function I mean wrap everything in `DatoramaSocial.R` in a function (or several subfunctions). The code for that function can easily reside in the external script file or be pasted before the `ui` and `server` statements in your shiny app. If the former, simply include the definitions by calling `source('DatoramaSocial.R')` *before* your `ui` and `server` statements.

Now, in your `server` function, you can simply call it as a reaction to changes in the input:

```
observe({
  DatoramaSocial(input$startDate, input$endDate, input$Brand, input$Medium, input$Camp)
})
```

Although in this case, I recommend inserting an `actionbuttonInput` and having the user click that when they have selected all their inputs. In which case, update to:

```
observeEvent(input$actionbutton, ignoreInit=TRUE, {
  DatoramaSocial(input$startDate, input$endDate, input$Brand, input$Medium, input$Camp)
})
```

where `actionbutton` is the actionbutton's inputId.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I created the function and the button, but then I have a error saying 'object response not found'.  Do you know where this could come from? Thanks!