# Passing Shiny Object to R script

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way that we can pass Shiny objects to embedded or outside R script? Like if I create a dateInput(let's say, ME_DATE) in ui and try to pass it in a sourced code later in server, how can it be done?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
dateInput("ME_DATE_output",label=h2("Execution Date"), value="2020-05-29")
)))

server = function(input, output) { 
ME_DATE_GUI <- reactive({input$ME_DATE_output})
Code_loc <- "K:/Codes/"
ME_DATE <<- renderPrint({ ME_DATE_GUI() })
source(paste0(Code_loc,"Passed_R_code.r"))
}
```

And that Passed_R_code.R starts with -

```
ME_DATE <- as.Date(ME_DATE, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

I also tried `as.character` in it.

The error I get is -

```
Error in as.Date.default: do not know how to convert 'ME_DATE' to class “Date”
```

Clearly passed ME_DATE isn't taking a value in YYYY-MM-DD format but some function. I am hoping there might be a step/function to convert this.
Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the mistakes of not assigning ME_DATE in reactive and then not declaring source as `local = TRUE`-

```
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
dateInput("ME_DATE_output",label=h2("Execution Date"), value="2020-05-29")
)))

server = function(input, output) { 
ME_DATE_GUI <- reactive({ME_DATE <-input$ME_DATE_output})
Code_loc <- "K:/Codes/"
source(paste0(Code_loc,"Passed_R_code.r"),local=TRUE)
}
```

I noticed the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54572066/6877763